# Chevy Malibu 2009 coolant sensor

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, sensor, temperature, malibu

I have a problem with my malibu, I got a code on the obdii reader as though the coolant temperature reading is not correct, so in the car lcd on the instrument cluster I can see Coolant temperature : -- C. The problem is through my OBDII, I am able to get a reading from the ect sensor which seems correct and makes sense. Has anyone experienced this problem before ?

Comment: Which engine do you have in your Malibu? 2.4, 2.4 Hybrid, 3.5, or 3.6?

Comment: It is the hybrid model ! 2.4 ecotec

Comment: what's the code? can you communicate with the instrument cluster module?

Comment: Sometimes when your coolant temperature sensor goes bad then it can send a false signal to the computer. It may have sent a false signal